# How to use if statement in a trigger using SQL

Tags: sql, database, triggers, db2

I have the following tables in my IBMDB2 database:

> Produt(PID....etc)
>       CombosAndPromotions(CP_ID, CP_Price...etc)
>       PriceSize(size, price)
>       Sales(PID, CP_ID, size, quantity, Sales_Price)

I want to create a trigger to automatically calculate the value of the Sales_Price. Basically

> 1-if the PID is null then the value is the price of the CP_ID * quantity.
>
> 2- if the CP_ID is null then the value of the Sales_Price is the price of the size of the Product bought(the price depends on the size not on the PID) * the quantity.
>
> 3-if Both of them are not null then the value of the Sales_Price is equal to the sum of both of the previous summations. I have tried the following SQL code, but it's not working.

```
create trigger calc_Price
after insert on sales
for every row mode db2sql 

if CP_ID is null
update table Sales
set Price = (PriceSize.price)*Quantity
where Sales.size = PriceSize.size

if PID is null
update table Sales
set price = CombosAndPromotions.CP_price * quantity
where CombosAndPromotions.CP_ID = Sales.CP_ID
```

can someone assist me on how to correct it since I don't have experience with sql.
thank you.

Comment: Triggers are very database specific.. which database are you using?

Comment: @thebjorn i'm using IBMdb2

Comment: Then you need the `then` keyword and `end if;` in your if statements (certain other databases like sql server and sybase don't require this).  You also need a `begin` and `end` around the trigger body (possibly with `atomic` after `begin`..)

Comment: @thebjorn can you please give me a simple demonstration on how can i use these keys, i will really appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

It's been a very long time since I used db/2, but something like this might work:

```
create trigger calc_Price
after insert on sales
referencing new as n
for every row mode db2sql 
begin atomic
    declare cpprice int;

    if n.CP_ID is null then
        update table Sales
            set Price = (n.price) * n.Quantity
        where PID = n.PID
    end if;

    if n.PID is null then
        set cpprice = (select CP_price from CombosAndPromotions where CP_ID = n.CP_ID)
        update table Sales
           set price = cpprice * n.quantity
        where PID = n.PID
    end if;
end
```

The idea is to reference the newly inserted row (here as `n`) and use the key from that row to update the table.  (this might work better as a before insert..?)

Comment: Thanks a lot @thebjorn, although the code is not working but it will help me fix the errors and correct everything. thank you

Comment: Please feel free to edit my answer with the correct code once you get it working :-)